# JavaFXML app shows zoomed resolution in NetBeans

Tags: javafx, netbeans, fxml, netbeans-8, scenebuilder

In **SceneBuilder** I have set my root pane(**Anchor Pane**) to *1280 x 720* and it shows the same thing in preview, however when I run my code in **NetBeans** my program is shown bigger than my full HD screen (*1920 x 1080*).

To resolve this I lowered my set resolution in **SceneBuilder** to something less and now it shows a smaller window when ran from **NetBeans** but it looks zoomed in and the size is still bigger than what it should be.

What can I do in **NetBeans** to show accurate size of stage(*window*) i.e size that I have created in **SceneBuilder**.

Comment: I have my resolution at 1920 x 1080 and I just created a 1280 x 720 in SceneBuilder. It did not reproduce your problem. I was able to duplicate your problem when I set my `Change the size of text, apps, and other items:` from `100%` to `150%`. This is basically asking for things to be bigger than they should.

Answer (score 0):

You can use many methods and add them to anchorPane. 
For Example:

```
anchorPane.setPrefSize(double prefWidth, double prefHeight)
```

In Netbeans. Here is link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#setPrefsize-double-

And you can find other methods in that documentation. For example: setMinWidth(double), setMinHeight(double), etc...

If you want to be 100% sure that your window is always 1280 x 720 then set:

```
        anchorPane.setMinWidth(1280);
        anchorPane.setMaxWidth(1280);
        anchorPane.setMinHeight(720);
        anchorPane.setMaxHeight(720);
```

where "anchorPane" can be Fx Id of your Anchor Pane.

EDIT: You can set them in initialize method.
Maybe you want to set size of Stage, then use stage instead of anchorPane.

Comment: I tried to set the stage size itself to 1280 x 720 in NetBeans and it still shows the same enlarged window.

Comment: So you set size of stage to 1280x720 with 
stage.setMinWidth(1280),
stage.setMaxWidth(1280),
stage.setMaxHeight(720),
stage.setMinHeight(720) 
And your stage is still 1920 x 1080?